# mysql super user error: definer = root @localhost

Tags: php, mysql

I'm throwing the below error when I'm trying to upload my db. I've tried in terminal and through phpmyadmin. I get the same error for both:

```
SQL query:

DELIMITER ; ;

/*!50003 CREATE*//*!50017 DEFINER=`root`@`localhost`*//*!50003 TRIGGER trg_catalog_category_entity_after_insert AFTER INSERT ON catalog_category_entity FOR EACH ROW BEGIN INSERT IGNORE INTO `enterprise_url_rewrite_category_cl` (`entity_id`) VALUES (NEW.`entity_id`); INSERT IGNORE INTO `catalog_category_product_cat_cl` (`category_id`) VALUES (NEW.`entity_id`); INSERT IGNORE INTO `catalog_category_flat_cl` (`entity_id`) VALUES (NEW.`entity_id`); END */ ; ;


MySQL said: Documentation

#1227 - Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER privilege(s) for this operation
```

In terminal i don't have access to root because of the shared server situation.

I pulled this DB from another store and I'm setting it up on another server. If I can actually get past this error.

I've tried changing users and adding new users and updating privileges and grants but nothing seems to work.

Comment: if this is a shared host, they likely have a method of creating databases in some type of control panel. Generally you create the DB and a user to access it via the host's web based control panel.. often called cpanel.

Comment: Did you flush the privileges ?

Comment: @DuaneLortie, that's correct but when i login to cpanel and upload the db through phpMyAdmin I still get the error. Also, uploading through phpMyAdmin has always been problematic in the past.

Comment: Hi @JazZ, since it was an existing DB and i'm moving it to a new server would that work just to flush privileges? What exactly does that do, does it just remove the root privileges that it's beckoning about inside the db?

Comment: To answer your question, no, i haven't tried that yet. How do i flush privileges on that db?

Comment: See this link : [When Privilege Changes Take Effect](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/privilege-changes.html). I'm not sure this is the problem but maybe...

Comment: Hum this seem not necessary... [When is Flush Privileges in MySQL really needed?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36463966/when-is-flush-privileges-in-mysql-really-needed) but you could try.

Comment: Now I'm getting this error: Access denied; you need (at least one of) the RELOAD privilege(s) for this operation

Comment: you are apparently trying to set user permissions in your import, thats not likely to be allowed since again, they want you to use their cpanel for that

Answer (score -1):

login using root priv

```
mysql -u root -p
```

and try this one

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `%`.* TO 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

it's work for me

Comment: That does not look like a valid solution. The OP states "i don't have access to root", and on a shared server, he never will get such permissions

Comment: Oh i m sorry for that but you can't without root access