# Cannot connect to mysql programmatically

Tags: java, mysql

I have setup mysql (mariadb) on linux machiche. I have created a user 'newuser' like:

```
CREATE USER 'newuser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * TO 'newuser'@'localhost';
```

when i do :

```
select user,password from user;
```

i can see:

```
+--------------+-------------------------------------------+
| user         | password                                  |
+--------------+-------------------------------------------+
| root         | *password                                 |
| newuser      | *password                                 |
+--------------+-------------------------------------------+
```

and when i execute this command :

```
select user();

+----------------+
| user()         |
+----------------+
| root@localhost |
+----------------+
```

I am trying to connect to my database using java but i am getting below exception:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create connection:Access denied for user 'newuser'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for newuser@localhost                                                                                                              |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'newuser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*7ABDF971526E9441B919C9FE77D50DB0363B3509' WITH GRANT OPTION |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Java code to connect to db:

```
try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    //  Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionString);
        Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/iot?autoReconnect=true","newuser","password");
        System.out.println("Connected --->"  + connection);
        return connection;
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        throw new SQLException("Cannot create connection:" + e.getMessage());
    }
```

Can anyone help me what i am missing?

Comment: did you `flush`?

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca yes i have used flush privileges;

Comment: Using `GRANT` does not require flushing - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36463966/when-is-flush-privileges-in-mysql-really-needed

Comment: @tomaytotomato yep, I found that while looking for documentation to point OP to. I'll just leave my comment there as a testament to my own ignorance.

Comment: @Rohitesh try this and see what it says `SHOW GRANTS FOR 'newuser'@'localhost'`

Comment: @tomaytotomato i have updated the answer please check

Comment: @Rohitesh please paste the java code used to connect to the DB.

Comment: @AlexiusDiakogiannis updated in question please check.

Comment: @Rohitesh can you try `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'newuser2'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';` and try to connect with newuser2? Also what version are you using?

Comment: @AlexiusDiakogiannis Server version: 10.1.23-MariaDB-9+deb9u1 Raspbian 9.0

Comment: @Rohitesh I dont see the Grant usage permission above and I guess this causes the issue.

Comment: @AlexiusDiakogiannis where exactly you are pointing?

Answer (score 1):

Try to connect to mysql and do

```
update user set host = '%' where user = 'newuser';
flush privileges;
```

Try to connect again. If you succeed then (as I suspect) you are NOT running the code on the same machine as mysql. You need to find the ip of your local machine (ifconfig on linux, ipconfig on windows) and execute

```
update user set host = 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.' where user = 'newuser';
flush privileges;
```

to allow connections from your ip (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx) only.

To revert changes execute

```
update user set host = 'localhost' where user = 'newuser';
flush privileges;
```

Comment: now its getting connected but one thing i want to know i am running mysql on rashbeery and trying to connect using remote machine using mysql workbench why its not connecting from workbench . Do i need to allow the tcp connection for remote connection?

Comment: You are probably trying to connect from workbench as root so you need to re-run the procedure for the root user or use the option in workbench in order to use an ssh tunnel. Since you managed to connect and my answer help you to identify and solve the issue can you be so kind to mark my answer as a solution? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Do you actually connect from the local machine? If not, you should substitute the "localhost" with a description of your host.

Comment: @danielmetzer what actually you mean to say can you please elobrate ?

Answer (score 0):

As per your scenario, I think you should have used

```
    FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

In case of modification of privilege FLUSH not needed as it will be reloaded but here you are creating new user and grant new privilege to new user so try with FLUSH PRIVILEGES.

I have used the following steps and it is working fine here:-

```
CREATE USER 'newuser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * TO 'newuser'@'localhost';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Now login with new newuser:-

```
     mysql -u newuser -p
     password
     show GRANTS;
```

```
    Output:- 
    +------------------------------------------------------+
    | Grants for newuser@localhost                         |
    +------------------------------------------------------+
    | GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'newuser'@'localhost' |
    +------------------------------------------------------+
```

As select user()  -- It will show current user which is logged in.
 SELECT User FROM mysql.user   ---It will show all users created in mysql.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        //  Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionString);
            Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/iot?autoReconnect=true","newuser","password");
            System.out.println("Connected --->"  + connection);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new SQLException("Cannot create connection:" + e.getMessage());
        } 

        }
```

It is running without error.I don't see any issues here.Have a look on it.

Comment: FLUSH PRIVILEGES; is NOT needed and if you read carefully the comments he has tried it with no success.

Comment: Yeah ! Then  It is IP issue as 10.1.23-MariaDB-9+deb9u1 Raspbian 9.0   must be  connecting on different addresses. It is not privilege problem.  java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create connection    means it must be connecting to some other host as  As password and user name seems correct.