# Does removal of access to a user affect current connections?

Tags: mysql

If I (or my DBAs) revoke a user's access to a MySQL database, what will happen to the existing connections?

In particular, if an app is using a persistent connection to talk to the database, will it get affected immediately when the access is revoked?

Comment: Try it and see?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When is Flush Privileges in MySQL really needed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36463966/when-is-flush-privileges-in-mysql-really-needed)

Comment: This is not exactly a dupe.  I am coming from a world unaware of `FLUSH PRIVILEGES` aspect of MySQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to manual [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/revoke.html):

> A revoked role immediately affects any user account from which it was
>   revoked, such that within any current session for the account, its
>   privileges are adjusted for the next statement executed.
>
> Revoking a role revokes the role itself, not the privileges that it
>   represents. If an account is granted a role that includes a given
>   privilege, and is also granted the privilege explicitly or another
>   role that includes the privilege, the account still is granted that
>   privilege after the first role is revoked. For example, if an account
>   is granted two roles that each include SELECT, the account still can
>   select after either role is revoked.