# Which username and password does mysqldump expect?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to make a copy of my website's database, so that I can download it and import it into wamp for local testing.

Here is what I'm entering in Putty:

```
mysqldump -u my_database_username -p dataname_db.sql --single-transaction --quick --lock-tables=false > dataname_db_local-$(date +%F).sql && gzip dataname_db_local.sql
```

No matter what combo of user and pass I use, I get this error

```
Got error: 1044: "Access denied for user to database when selecting the database
```

It wants the MySQL user that has full privileges to that database, right? ie the same credentials as what I use to connect to the database in a new MySQLi() command in php, right?

I read that sometimes passwords with special characters aren't allowed, so I made a new user, full priveleges, for that database with a plain alphanumeric pass, but it's still not accepted.

I then thought maybe it wants the same username and pass as what I use to connect to my server via Putty, but that didn't work. Neither did -u root with the server password.

Can someone please clarify exactly which username it wants?

Thank you

Comment: I'm not entirely sure but have you restarted the service or do [FLUSH PRIVILEGES](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36463966/mysql-when-is-flush-privileges-in-mysql-really-needed) after you created the new user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are right, `mysqldump` requires exactly the same `username` and `password` as what you use to connect to the database in a new MySQLi() command in php.

Make sure your account has `Lock_Table` privilege.

If it still didn't work, try to pass the –-single-transaction option to mysqldump:

```
mysqldump --single-transaction -u db_username -p DBNAME > backup.sql
```

Notice that there is a `syntax` problem, you should select your DB at last of mysqldump statement:

```
mysqldump [options] db_name [tbl_name ...] > filename.sql
```

Reference: [[1]](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/86991/mysqldump-got-error-1044-access-denied-for-user-usernamelocalhost-to-dat) , [[2]](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mysqldump/)