# Created privileged user - mysql asks for password

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I'm following a text tutorial, where I create a user:

```
 create user 'APP'@'localhost' identified by 'APP';
 grant all privileges on *.* to 'APP'@'localhost';
 quit
```

When I try to login to the user with:

```
mysql -u APP -p
```

I'm asked a password. Entering the password give me the error:

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'APP'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

Which password does the created user have?

Comment: It's "APP", as specified?

Comment: @Progman Sadly that doesn't work.

Comment: "identified by 'APP';" This literally says APP is your password. Else you executed another user

Comment: _Entering the password give me the error:_ Entering WHAT as the password

Comment: @StriggyBurger Does it also not work when you run `FLUSH PRIVILEGES` or restart the MySQL server (even though it shouldn't be necessary)?

Comment: please dont put SOLVED stuff in the question. Thats why there is an answer space, once its accepted then that indicates a solution

Comment: Usually you don't need `FLUSH PRIVILEGES` when adding a user. It looks like you did something else before (or after), which is not present in your question to reproduce this issue.

Comment: actually ``FLUSH PRIVILEGES;`` is necessary, otherwise the changes are not saved and it is as if you have not created anything. Maybe that was in versions older than [MYSQL 5.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36463966/mysql-when-is-flush-privileges-in-mysql-really-needed). @Progman

Comment: in my case it was compulsory because it was not applied and I solved it with flush.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *identified by* portion is where you are setting a password for a user. So 'APP' is the password.

Edit: You may also need to execute *FLUSH PRIVILEGES;* for the change to take affect.

Comment: I get `ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'APP'@'localhost' (using password: YES)`. :c

Comment: Try FLUSH PRIVILEGES; and attempt sign on again

Comment: don't forget to mark the correct solution @StriggyBurger

Comment: Yep, I will. There's a timer. I have to wait a little bit.

Comment: there is a timer as long as it is your question and it auto answers you but another user has written to your question with an answer so you can already accept the answer.