# MySQL 5.6 - User cannot view stored procedure code

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

We created a user/login for some devs, and we have an issue where this user/login cannot view stored procedure code.

This is for MySQL 5.6.

I checked the GRANTS and also the information_schema (schema_privileges) and things look "good" to me.

Here are the commands I used to GRANT the database access and privileges:

```
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, CREATE VIEW, SHOW VIEW, CREATE ROUTINE, ALTER ROUTINE ON `mydatabase`.*  TO 'dev-user'@'%' ;
```

After that, I run the FLUSH PRIVILEGES command.
And, when I run  `` SHOW GRANTS for `dev-user` ``  , I get the following response:

GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, CREATE VIEW, SHOW VIEW, CREATE ROUTINE, ALTER ROUTINE ON `mydatabase`.* TO 'dev-user'@'%'

After that the user runs the command `SHOW CREATE  procedure mydatabase.sp_test` and the output has NULL in the CREATE PROCEDURE Column.

This same user/login can create a new procedure and running  `SHOW CREATE procedure`  has the procedure code visible in that CREATE PROCEDURE column.

And, as a quick test, i created another user with `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES`  on the database and i get the same results.  That user also not see the stored procedure code.

When I run a query on the information_schema.SCHEMA_PRIVILEGES system table, i can see that the user has included:

- ALTER
- ALTER ROUTINE
- CREATE
- CREATE ROUTINE

Does anyone have any suggestions or can see something i am missing, or forgot?

Thanks for any help

Comment: [SHOW CREATE PROCEDURE Statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/show-create-procedure.html) To use either statement, you must be the user named in the routine `DEFINER` clause or have `SELECT`access to the `mysql.proc` table. If you do not have privileges for the routine itself, the value displayed for the Create Procedure or Create Function column is NULL.

Comment: *"Does anyone have any suggestions or can see something i am missing, or forgot?"* Does the user also have `SELECT` on the `mysql.proc` table ???

Comment: hi @RaymondNijland

Thanks for the comments.  I actually just re-read the mysql manual for that CREATE PROCEDURE command and it pointed to the same issue.  
So, i granted SELECT to that user on the mysql.proc table and it worked.
I will mark your response as THE ANSWER!  :)
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/show-create-procedure.html):

> To use either statement, you must be the user named in the routine `DEFINER` clause or have `SELECT` access to the `mysql.proc` table.

So grant them that access:

```
GRANT SELECT ON mysql.proc TO 'dev-user'@'%';
```

BTW, it's not necessary to use `FLUSH PRIVILEGES` after the `GRANT` statement. See [MySQL: When is Flush Privileges in MySQL really needed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36463966/mysql-when-is-flush-privileges-in-mysql-really-needed)